# How does debian package fix versioning of dependencies?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I went through a couple of tutorials on creating debian packages. It all seems somewhat straightforward. All that is required to do is to create a control file listing the dependencies and just run "dpkg" on the directory to be packed.

What is not clear is how the packaging mechanism fix dependencies. For example, let's say my executable is dependent on libxxx.so.23 (as seen by running ldd). When the package is installed on a client machine, it will automatically download "xxx" package and perhaps result in creating libxxx.so.1 on the client machine. How does the packaging mechanism fix the executable to point to libxxx.so.1 and not libxxx.so.23?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: We don't build packages by running `dpkg` on the directory to be packad. We run `debuild` (well actually `dpkg-buildpackage`, but `debuild is nicer`) in the unpacked source package.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. `libxxx.so.23` is in the package libxxx23, not the generic libxxx-dev, and `dh_shlibdeps` introduces a dependency on libxxx23. Unversioned packages (xxx or libxxx) are very rare and are probably a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am still confused. Looking at the control file for VLC media player, I see that the depends section does not mention specific version but something like libstdc++6 (>= 4.2.1). How does that work? Also, we know that VLC requires ffmpeg (libavcodec). However, it is not even in the depends list. What is it that I am missing?